# How to calculate probabilities in a Brownian motion?

Tags: calculus, probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, random-variables

I have a Brownian motion, $X(t)$.

Here, $T_a$ $=$ $inf($$t:$ $X(t) = a$$)$

And $M(t)$ $=$ $max($$X(s) : $  $0 ≤ s ≤ t$$)$.

I am trying to prove that:

$P(T_a \le t) =$ $2$$\int_a^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{2t\pi}} e^{\frac{-u^2}{2t}} du$

For this, I am trying to use the fact that $P(T_a \le t) = P(M(t) > a)$

I have been trying various ways to work it out.  But it looks like I am missing something or I'm not on the right track.  Any help will be very useful.  Thank you so much!

Comment: See [reflexion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_principle_(Wiener_process))

Comment: @Surb Thank you for the link!  I worked through this, and I see that we can directly apply the reflexion principle to the question here if $X(t), t \ge 0$ is a standard Brownian motion, i. e., if $X(t)$ ~ $N(0, t)$.  Suppose $X(t)$ is just a Brownian motion (not standard).  In this case, does the principle hold, and if so, how can we use it to show that $P(T_a \le t) =$ $2$$\int_a^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{2t\pi}} e^{\frac{-u^2}{2t}} du$ ?  Thank you very much for your time.